# Detect file path from a given string contains special chars

Tags: c#, regex, string, filepath

My code collects many file paths. File paths often contain some special characters(prefix or postfix). I want to derive a regular expression to detect and extract only the file path from a given string out of any number of special characters or any characters (it should extract exactly starting from Drive letter and ends with File-extension) using C#.

**Ex.**

//If the path contains something like below

```
string filPath = "\\??\\C:\\Windows\System32\\appidcertstorecheck.exe\\%%";
```

then it should return...

```
filPath = "C:\\Windows\System32\\appidcertstorecheck.exe";
```

Please help me out!

Comment: What work have you attempted? Without work from you, this will be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help `\w:.*\.\w+`

**Explanation**

- `\w`matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
- `:` matches the character `:` literally (case sensitive)

  - `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)
  - `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `\.` matches the character . literally (case sensitive)

  - `\w+` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
  - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

**Outputs**

```
C:\\Windows\System32\\appidcert.storecheck.exe
```

from

```
\\??\\C:\\Windows\System32\\appidcert.storecheck.exe\\%%";
```

[**Demo here**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cw%3a.*%5c.%5cw%2b&i=%5c%5c%3f%3f%5c%5cC%3a%5c%5cWindows%5cSystem32%5c%5cappidcert.storecheck.exe%5c%5c%25%25%22%3b)

Comment: Both groupings seem to be unnecessary

Comment: @TheGeneral: Thanks for your kind help, yes it worked perfectly. I don't know why the question is down-rated. `Regex.Match(pathString.ToString(), @"\w:.*\.\w+").Groups[0].Value;` could pull the exact path for me. As my code used to analyze files, often the file path consists of special-chars and I had to get a regex to deal such cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **FileInfo** and Pass the string to its constructor. If it's invalid string (not a path). it will throw **ArgumentException**
OR something like this may help :

```
^([a-zA-Z]\:)(\\[^\\/:*?<>"|]*(?<![ ]))*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$
```

**Update**
The thongs that I should strongly mention is that path can contain Unicode, Or it can be relative. then using Regex may not be a good Idea. also, there are rules for a file name and ... in windows which should be considered.

Comment: Using exceptions for controlling program flow is usually a bad idea, because it makes the code slow.

Comment: @UweKeim you are right, if you don't consider Unicode. if you consider then there will be no way other FileInfo (I suppose)